# Session not working using php

Tags: php, session

When I login into index.php then the page redirect to dashboard.php but when I press back page, It still redirect index.php but in my code, when the session is still existing then even I click the back page it will redirect to dashboard.php not index.php but it's not working.

> index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
"<script>location.replace('dashboard.php'); </script>";
}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html >
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Media Development APAC</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
   <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'>
   <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>

 <body style="background-color: #333333">


 <div class="pen-title">
   <h1>Media Development APAC</h1>
 </div>
 <!-- Form Module-->
 <div class="module form-module">
   <div class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-times fa-pencil"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="form">
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
   <h2>Login to your account</h2>
  <form>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"></button>
  </form>
 </div>
  <div class="form">

  </div>
</div>
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <script src='https://codepen.io/andytran/pen/vLmRVp.js'></script>
   <script src="js/index.js"></script>

<?php
                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

                            $username = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
                            $password = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
                            $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysqli_error());
                            $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                                if( $num_row > 0 ) {

                            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];

                                    ?>  
     <script>alert('Login Successful');
    window.location='dashboard.php';</script>
   <?php


                                }

                                else{
                            }}
                            ?>
```

> dashboard.php

```
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('navbar_dashboard.php'); ?>

     <body><h1>Dashboard</h1></body>
```

> session.php

```
  <?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();

   } ?> 
      <?php

    if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) {

   ?>     <script>window.location='index.php';</script> <?php
   exit();
 }
  $session_id=$_SESSION['id'];

 ?>
```

[Index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JLfT.png)   [dashboard.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s67OD.png)

Comment: Only use blockquotes for actual quotes and use bold sparingly for emphasis, not to attract attention, so please remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use php for these types of redirect.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

**This may be solution**

```
echo "<script>.....</script>";
```

You forgot to use **echo**

Comment: Wahahaha thank you so much I'm full of stress and didn't think that's the problem of my code. thank you my friend!

Comment: Try not to use javascript for stuff like redirects as javascript is not reliable